# jQuery alternative for inline javascript with parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

Which would be the alternative in jquery for the following code?

```
function doSomething(par1, par2, par3) {
    // process something with the parameters
}

.
.
.
<div>
    <input type="button" value="Process" onclick="doSomething('a', 'b', 'c');"></input><br />
    <input type="button" value="Process" onclick="doSomething('d', 'e', 'f');"></input><br />
    <input type="button" value="Process" onclick="doSomething('g', 'h', 'i');"></input><br />
</div>
```

The arguments used in doSomething were created on server side.
Thanks!

Edit: complementing the question

this would be the best way?

```
// On server side
$(function() {
    $('selector').click({par1:a, par2:b, par3:c}, function() {
       // process something with the parameters
    });
    $('selector').click({par1:d, par2:e, par3:f}, function() {
       // process something with the parameters
    });
    $('selector').click({par1:g, par2:g, par3:i}, function() {
       // process something with the parameters
    });
});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: I edited the question, would this the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alternate of calling a function on click and passing variables to it?
You'd have to restructure your input so that some perimeter other than onlcick(maybe the 'value?') has the arguments you're wanting to pass and then this would be the javascript.

```
<div>
     <input type="button" value="a,b,c"></input>
</div>


function doSomething(argumentsToManipulate) {
   ///expects an array of arguments
}


$('input').click(function(){
  ///passedArguments will be an ['a','b','c']
  var passedArguments = $(this).attr('value').split(',');
  doSomething(passedArguments);
});
```

Also, I'm curious why you're not using classes or IDs as this would make the jquery selection much more specific.

Comment: If I set the value attribute with my arguments they will be displayed on screen and class and id I use for another purpose. The problem is to pass the arguments to the jquery.

Comment: I would then suggest using an html5 data attribute. Using `data-value` instead of `value` in the HTML and then using `$(this).attr('data-value')` instead of `$(this).attr('value')`.

Comment: The data-* attribute solved my problem, on server side I set the value dynamically for the "data-id" and on my page I get it with jQuery. Thanks!